# Basic PHP entry failing

Tags: php, mysql

I'm setting up a wedding invitation RSVP form. I have here what should be a basic PHP and SQL data entry, but I keep getting the error:

"Could not enter data: No database selected"

UPDATE - Many thanks to all your suggestions. I have updated my code as you can see bellow. I now get a new error as follows:

"Could not connect:" (witch is a message I output myself in line 7, but it does not show the error that should follow")

Does anyone know what this means please?

Here is my [UPDATED] code:

```
 <?php
function submit(){
  $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "jaredand_rsvp", "jar3dandcr1st1na", "jaredand_rsvp");

  if (!$con)
  {
    die('Could not connect: ' . $con->error);
  }
  $name = $_POST['name'];
  $partnerName = $_POST['partner_name'];
  $allergies = $_POST['allergies'];
  $comments = $_POST['comment'];
  $going = $_POST['going'];

  $sql =  'INSERT INTO rsvp '.
          '(name,partner_name, allergies, comments, going) '.
          'VALUES ( "'.$name.'", "'.$partnerName.'", "'.$allergies.'", "'.$comments.'", "'.$going.'")';         

  $result = $con->query($sql);

  if(!$result )
  {
    die('Could not enter data: ' . $result->error);
  }
  echo "Entered data successfully\n";

  mysqli_close($con);
}

if(isset($_POST['name']))
{ 
  submit();
} 
?>
```

Can anyone please advise me on what I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: database connection has not been set here `$con = mysql_connect("localhost","USERNAME","PASSWORD", "DATABASENAME");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is the right way

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","USERNAME","PASSWORD);
mysql_select_db('jaredand_rsvp', $con);
```

but please use "mysqli"

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "USERNAME", "PASSWORD, "jaredand_rsvp");
$result = $con->query($sql);
```

happy to help,
for security is better if you escape your values before insert :

```
  $name = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
  $partnerName = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['partner_name']);
  $allergies = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['allergies']);
  $comments = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['comment']);
  $going = $con->real_escape_string($_POST['going']);
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I believe that I have done this now, but still no luck.

Comment: if you use mysqli use " $con->error " not  " mysql_error() "... let me know if the error is the same

Comment: You mean like this ? die('Could not connect: ' .$con->error)

Comment: Thanks, tried that. Still only get "could not connect"

Comment: actually I ment  : "die('Could not connect: ' .mysqli_connect_error())  " And... "  die('Could not enter data: ' . $con->error); "

Comment: Ok great, thanks for that. I now have a meaningful error. It seems I do not have access. I will go and check my usernames and passwords and speak to the host, but I hope this will solve my problem :) Thanks again, will let you know how it turns out.

Comment: It seems that I just needed to give myself user permissions from c-panel. It seems to be working now. Thanks for your continuous assistance :) I truly  appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

That happens because mysql_connect doesn't have database name as parameter.

You should connect to the server, and then select a database by calling `mysql_select_db`

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect to the database first and then select the database name

I hope this will fix your issue

Or you could use PDO because mysql_connect is depricated

Answer (score 0):

How about using MySQLi instead of the now depreciated MySQL?

**EDIT**

Okay, I see no connection being made to the database. Something like

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

If you have stored the db connect credential on a different file then i see no include or require mentioned on your this script either. Check if you have made the connection and then get back.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I believe that I have done this now, but still no luck.

Comment: @phunder, i updated my answer, please check and then respond.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I have already managed to fix my error with Federico's help as you should be able to see above :)

Answer (score 0):

You have used $con = mysql_connect(); at the top and bottom you are using:
mysqli_close();

First follow the same standarad. Use mysqli instead of sqli at top.i.e, 
`$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","USERNAME","PASSWORD", "jaredand_rsvp");`

Remove the line: `mysql_select_db('jaredand_rsvp');`
and replace `$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $con );`    with
`$retval = mysqli_query( $sql, $con );`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I believe that I have done this now, but still no luck.

Comment: It just says "Could not connect:" I posted this and my updated code above :) Thanks again for the reply

Comment: Have you make a database at backend with same name?

Answer (score 0):

**Use it another Way**

```
<?php
    function submit() {
        $host = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $dbname = "jaredand_rsvp";

        $con = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $dbname);
        if ($conn -> connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn -> connect_error);
        }


        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $partnerName = $_POST['partner_name'];
        $allergies = $_POST['allergies'];
        $comments = $_POST['comment'];
        $going = $_POST['going'];

        $sql = 'INSERT INTO rsvp ' . '(name,partner_name, allergies, comments, going) ' . 'VALUES ( "' . $name . '", "' . $partnerName . '", "' . $allergies . '", "' . $comments . '", "' . $going . '")';

        if($con->query($sql)== TRUE){
        echo "Data Inserted";
        }
    else {
            echo mysqli_error($con);
    }


        mysqli_close($con);
    }

    if (isset($_POST['name'])) {
        submit();
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried using your code, but still no luck.

Comment: $sql = "INSERT INTO rsvp  name,partner_name, allergies, comments, going   VALUES  '$name',' $partnerName ',' $allergies',' $comments', '$going' ";           // change on here and tell me what is the error shows ?